# Python - Tkinter and Google Sheets - File not found

Tags: python, tkinter, google-sheets, pyinstaller, pygsheets

Anyone knows how to solve this one?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pygsheets\sheet.py", line 39, in _init_
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Asus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI102362\\pygsheets\\data\\sheets_discovery.json'
```

I'm trying to make an app to write some data on a Google Sheets file using Tkinter, pygsheets and pyinstaller.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's telling you it can't find the file, you can be pretty sure it can't find the file. It looks like you've got the wrong number of backslashes. Please show how you're creating or getting the filename.

Comment: did you add `pygsheets\data\sheets_discovery.json` to project (file `.spec`) when you run `PyInstaller`? Read documentation [Using Spec Files — PyInstaller 5.3 documentation](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html)